# Check visibility and height of the keyboard in android with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Tags: android

Now I use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and approach, described here: [How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android) to check if the keyboard is visible and to calculate it's size.

But now I want to change android:windowSoftInputMode to "adjustNothing".

I think that this approach will not work after this changes. 
Is there any other way to check the keyboard appearance/size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method that can help in implementing this: View.fitSystemWindows()