# Is it possible to detect visibility or not of the soft keyboard in android with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"?

Tags: android, android-view, android-softkeyboard

I have found [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425532/check-visibility-and-height-of-the-keyboard-in-android-with-androidwindowsoftin) a question same as my question. Unfortunately
, the answer is not complete and clear.

I aslo found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android) , but it only works with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

My requirement:

1. I want to change `android:windowSoftInputMode` to "`adjustNothing`".
2. I want to detect the soft keyboard shown or hide

How to do it?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Comment: @ThomasR. The solution can't work with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`

Comment: look into this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Comment: @KingofMasses I have tried. But it can't work with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`

Comment: @JerikcXIONG Did you found a solution?